# How to model a database structure for exam dates and date ranges?

Tags: database-design

I have one table `Exam`, and I want to store exam `Date`. Each `Exam` belongs to one of the `Categories` described below:

**Category 1**. For `Exam` *A*, there can be a `Date` once in a year, e.g.,  *01-01-2017*.

**Category 2**. For `Exam` *B*, there can be more than one `Date` during the same year, e.g., *01-01-2017* and *03-01-2017*.

**Category 3**. For `Exam` *C*, there can be a `Date` range, e.g., from *01-01-2017* to *10-01-2017*

**Category 4**. For `Exam` *D*, the `Date` can be chosen by a `Student`, e.g., the whole year, i.e., 365 days

**My approach**

I am *saving* the `Exam.Date(s)` in another table. I believe the relationship between `Exam` and `Date` is one-to-many. Said table would display data as follows:

[image]

**Question**

The problem with this approach is that, for `Category` *4*, each `Exam` will have *365* rows, so, is this approach correct?

Comment: for case 4 - You do not need store all 365 days, just store already chosen dates. Sudnet1 choose 01 Feb, Student 3 - 01 May, so table store only 2 records. And application allow Students choose any date from Calendar, but not from table

Answer (score 1):

I think I would approach this as the exam-dates table wouldn't have an entry for category 4, since it is an open-ended exam.

Perhaps, if you need to know when student A took an exam under category 4, then add a column for the date taken along with the student and student's grade?

So you could have

- an `Exam` table that lists out the exams and other data like course id, etc.
- an `ExamDates` table that lists when exams are scheduled (and possibly other  values like building, room number, etc.)
- a `Students` table with all of your student data.
- a `StudentExams` table that links exams to students, (and through exams back to courses). This would have a student ID, an Exam ID, a date the test was completed, and a grade.

and probably some other tables like

- a `Courses` table with data about the course
- a `StudentCourses` table linking student to course
- and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Got another approach-
Using two column EXAM_START_DATE and EXAM_END_DATE to save date in place of only 1 column EXMA_DATE.

- **For Category A -** there will be only one entry.

EXAM_START_DATE : 01-01-2017 EXAM_END_DATE : 01-01-2017

- **For Category B -** there will be two entries.

Row 1) EXAM_START_DATE : 01-01-2017 EXAM_END_DATE : 01-01-2017

Row 2) EXAM_START_DATE : 03-01-2017 EXAM_END_DATE : 03-01-2017

- **For Category C -** 
  there will be only one entry.

EXAM_START_DATE : 01-01-2017 EXAM_END_DATE : 10-01-2017

- **For Category D -** there will be only one entry.

EXAM_START_DATE : 01-01-2017 EXAM_END_DATE : 31-01-2017

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From first rows we clearly can see that dates and exams have many-to-many relationship:

- exam `B` has `01-01-17` and `03-01-17`
- on `01-01-17` there are two exams `A` and `B`

So standard way is to have separate tables for exams and dates and then have junction table to handle relationship.

For example:

```
Exam Id  ExamName  ...other data
1        A
2        B
3        C
...
```

```
DateId  Date      ...other data
1       01-01-17
2       02-01-17
...
```

```
ExamId  DateId
1       1
1       2
2       1
...
```

If dates don't have other data, then `Date` can easily be added in column in `Exam` (first table) table.